# Make Ajax Request Recursive - Checks if File Exists

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, recursion

Basically just looking to see if a particular txt file exists on the server, and if so, do further processing; however, I don't think my recursion is correct, so can someone offer a few pointers - here's what I have:

```
function fileExists(filename) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'HEAD',
        url: 'http://www.example.com/system/'+filename+'.txt',
        success: function() {
            // Further processing if file exists
        },  
        error: function() {
            // File does not exists, run through function again-
            return arguments.callee(filename);
        }
    });
}
```

It's pretty basic, there's some processing before hand that actually creates the file; however the issue is it's FTP-ed up to our domain, which means timing can vary by a few seconds, so basically I just want it to recheck until it sees that the file exists.  I'll modify it a little afterwards to control the stack, possibly setting a timeout of half a second or something, but I'm not that great with javascript, so I need a few pointers to make this recursive.  Any help is GREATLY appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the issue is when you try to call `fileExists` again via `arguments.callee(fileName)`, the scope of the `error` method isn't what you think it is.

Just call `fileExists`.

The other you are going to have is that if your server is quick, you are going to be firing a ton of requests. You probably want to wait some time between requests.  So make `error` contain

```
setTimeout(function(){
    console.log('trying again....'); // this won't work in IE, I *think*
    fileExists(filename);
}, 1000); // try again in a second
```

Finally, you should realize that the `error` callback only gets invoked if the server returns a 500.  The 500 code usually means there was an error on your server.  If a file doesn't exist, you should probably return json to indicate the file doesn't exist, and handle that case in your `success` callback.

Comment: How would I be able to check for a 404?  Just briefly looking at the jQuery ajax page I see that you can specify for certain status codes, i.e.`$.ajax({
  statusCode: {
    404: function() {
      alert('page not found');
    }
  }
});`

It seems like I'm stuck in a constant loop here, I set a 1 second timeout as you directed, and threw in an alert to make sure it was being executed (which it is) but I'm never receiving a success.

Comment: @pennstate_fanboy then the file is never being uploaded.  If you want to return a 404, then the code you referenced is the right direction. You can also have a attempts variable that you increment each time you check, and bail out if attempts > n, where you decide a reasonable n.

Comment: I like the attempts variable notion - will probably implement something similar to that.  However, would it make more sense instead of using `success()` and `error()` to check the status codes - i.e. `200` (do processing) and `404` (repeat function)?

Comment: @pennstate_fanboy The `success` callback is like having a `statuCode` callback for 200.  Similarly, the `error` callback is like having a `statusCode` callback for 500.  You should always handle those cases.  Just add a 404 callback in `statusCode`.

Answer (score 1):

```
error: function() {
            fileExists(filename); 
        }
```